# Python readlines() splits line into two

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading lines from a text file. In the text file there is a single word in each line. I can read and print the word from the file, but not the whole word is printed out on one line. The word is split into two. The letters of the printed word are mixed.

Here is my code:

```
import random
fruitlist = open('fruits.txt', 'r')

reading_line = fruitlist.readlines()
word = random.choice(reading_line)
mixed_word = ''.join(random.sample(word,len(word)))

print(mixed_word)

fruitlist.close()
```

How can I display one word on a line?

EDIT:

this is the content of the text file:

```
pinapple    
pear    
strawberry    
cherry    
papaya
```

The script should print one of these words (with their letters mixed) like this:

```
erpa
```

(This would be the equivalent of pear)

Right now it is displayed like this:

```
erp  
a
```

Comment: Can you please update your question to 1) clearly show what is desired output and actual output and 2) include a brief snippet of the file you are reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that's because you're also shuffling the line termination chars that `readlines` or line iterators include in the line. Use `strip()` to get rid of them (or `rstrip()`)

Do it like this (avoid `readlines` BTW):

```
with open('fruits.txt', 'r') as fruitlist:
    reading_line = [x.strip() for x in fruitlist]
    word = random.choice(reading_line)
    mixed_word = ''.join(random.sample(word,len(word)))
```